# Python - Python 3.1 can't seem to handle UTF-16 encoded files?

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

I'm trying to run some code to simply go through a bunch of files and write those that happen to be .txt files into the same file, removing all the spaces. Here's some simple code that should do the trick:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
for file in files:
    if '.txt' in file:
        f = open(subdir+'/'+file, 'r')
        line = f.readline()
        while line:
            line2 = line.split()
            if line2:
                output_file.write(" ".join(line2)+'\n')
            line = f.readline()
        f.close()
```

But instead, I get the following error:

**File "/usr/lib/python3.1/codecs.py", line 300, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: unexpected code byte**

It turns out these .txt files are all in UTF-16 (according to FireFox, at any rate). I thought Python 3.x was supposed to be able to handle any sort of character encoding??

Best,
Georgina

Comment: Can you just tell Python that the files are UTF-16?

Comment: Ok, oneliner: `output_file.write(input_file.read().decode('utf-16').replace(u" ", u"").encode('desired encoding'))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `open(bla, 'r', encoding="utf-16")`.

Comment: Woops--thanks! Just as you posted this, iI discovered this great post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140010/converting-from-utf-16-to-utf-8-in-python-3

Answer (score 6):

There are various utf-16 encodings.

- **utf-16-be** big endian no BOM
- **utf-16-le** little endian no BOM
- **utf-16** little endian + BOM

Examples:

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88452, Feb 20 2011, 11:12:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 'a'.encode('utf-16')
>>> a
b'\xff\xfea\x00'
>>> a.decode('utf-16')
'a'
>>> a = 'a'.encode('utf-16-le')
>>> a
b'a\x00'
>>> a.decode('utf-16-le')
'a'
>>> a = 'a'.encode('utf-16-be')
>>> a
b'\x00a'
>>> a.decode('utf-16-be')
'a'
```

You can use these encodings as suggested by [@filmor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644833/python-python-3-1-cant-seem-to-handle-utf-16-encoded-files/5644857#5644857)